# How to check if Oozie action had to retry to succeed

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue

In Oozie you can specify whether an action needs to retry after a certain retry-interval in case it fails. This can be done using the `retry-max` and `retry-interval` options. 
I have a workflow action which I know had to retry before it succeeded since it showed me the red `user-retry` status then stayed idle for a while before continuing.  When investigating the workflow from Hue it seems like nothing went wrong at all. I am wondering if this retry is logged somewhere and if I can easily find the number of retries in Hue. From Hue I can't seem to find it in the stdout, stderr or syslog of the action that eventually succeeded.

Comment: Currently Oozie UI does not show this information, which got add into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2691. Though this information is available in the database if you want.

Comment: Mm ok, having the possibility to look it up is already something. I think this will make a valuable addition to the UI though. Thanks for the answer